# Remove particular characters from lines and concatenate them

Tags: powershell

I have a problem where I need to cut specific characters from a line and then concatenate the line with the next lines, separated by commas.
Consider there is a text file `abc.txt` and I need the last 3 lines from the file. The last 3 lines are in the this format:

```
11/7/2000 17:22:54 -  Hello world.
19/7/2002 8:23:54  - Welcome to the new technology.
24/7/2000 9:00:13 - Eco earth
```

I need to remove the starting time stamp from each line and then concatenate the lines as

```
Hello world.,Welcome to the new technology,Eco earth.
```

The time stamp is not static and I want to make use of a regex

I tried the following:

```
$Words = (Get-Content -Path .\abc.txt|Select-Object -last 3|Out-String)
$Words = $Words -split('-')
$regex = "[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}):[0-9]{1,3}"
```

The output I used to get is like

```
11/7/2000 17:22:54 
Hello world
19/7/2002 8:23:54 
Welcome to the new technology.
24/7/2000 9:00:13 
Eco earth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to create a Regex that tries to figure out the timestamp part, because you want to skip that anyway.

This should work:

```
# read the file and get the last three lines as string array
$txt = Get-Content -Path 'D:\abc.txt' -Tail 3

# loop through the array and change the lines as you go
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $txt.Count; $i++) {
    $txt[$i] = ($txt[$i] -split '-', 2)[-1].Trim()
}
# finally, join the array with commas
$txt -join ','
```

Output:

> Hello world.,Welcome to the new technology.,Eco earth

Comment: I was able to get desired results

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\example.txt" | %{
$array=$_ -split "-", 2
$array[1].Trim()
}
```

Comment: I get an error as Unexpected token "array" in the expression or statement

Comment: Update your PowerShell version :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have for example : "DATE - blablabla"

If you do `.Split("-")` on it you get :

```
Date 
 blablabla
```

What you can do is $string.Split("-")[Which_Line] -> so

```
$string="12/15/18 08:05:10 - Hello World."
$string=$string.Split("-")[1]
```

Returns : `Hello world.` (with spaces before)

Now on string you can apply Trim() function - it removes spaces before and after your string

```
$string=$string.Trim()
```

Gives you `Hello world.`

---

For your answer, if it's static usage (always 3) :

```
$Words = (Get-Content -Path .\abc.txt|Select-Object -last 3|Out-String).Split("-")
$end=$Words[2].Trim() + "," + $Words[4].Trim() + "," + $Words[6].Trim()
```